# Like vs Would like

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> - Take one of these books if you 
>     like.
> - Take one of these books if you would like.

What is the difference in meaning ? And is it standard to say *would like* after if ? I think in standard English after if we put only the verb not would + verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation you describe, there is no difference or preferred way. However, if you were to say

> Would you like one of these books?

That has a different meaning than

> Do you like one of these books?

In the first example, there is an implication of receiving a book, like

> Would you like *to have* one of these books?

However, in the second one, the context is more about the word *like* as in *enjoy*.

**However**, in the particular phrasing you give, there is, again, no difference. It could be argued that *would* is implied in the first sentence. Although neither is preferred (grammatically), you will most likely hear the first one more just because it's shorter.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, **would** has this meaning in the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/would):

> 4. Expressing a polite request:
>      Would you pour the wine, please?

The second form is just a slightly more polite form of the first, along the same lines as

> Would you like a glass of wine?